# Navigating to "url", waiting until "load" - Python Playwright Issue

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Hey I have code in python playwright for getting page source:

```
import json
import sys
import bs4
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
server_proxy = urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[1])
link = urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[2])
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    #browser = p.chromium.launch(headless = False)
    browser = p.chromium.launch(proxy={"server": server_proxy,'username': 'xxx',"password": 'xxx' })
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36')
    page = context.new_page()
    cookie_file = open('cookies_tessco.json')
    cookies = json.load(cookie_file)
    context.add_cookies(cookies)
    page.goto(link)
    try:
        page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
        cont = page.content()
        print(cont)
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()      
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script." + page)
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

This works okay, but sometimes I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page_tessco.py", line 17, in <module>
    page.goto(link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 5774, in goto
    self._sync(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 103, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_page.py", line 464, in goto
    return await self._main_frame.goto(**locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_frame.py", line 117, in goto
    await self._channel.send("goto", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 36, in send
    return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 47, in inner_send
    result = await callback.future
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://www.tessco.com/product/207882", waiting until "load"
```

I tried to add

```
page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
```

but still, these errors appear sometimes, any help, also im confused why this error appears only sometimes, what causes this error, if someone has experience please share it?

Answer (score 4):

The URL `https://www.tessco.com/product/207882` loads quite slow.

Try to extend the default timeout of `30000ms` adding a timeout to `page.goto(link)`:

```py
page.goto(link, timeout = 0)
```

With setting `timeout` to `0` you disable the timeout. [Documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page/#page-goto)

Alternatively, you can disable timeout with the following:

```py
page.set_default_timeout(0)
page.goto(link)
```

Comment: I did it, however, i still sometimes receive the same error:

playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.

Comment: @HHHHHHT I tried your code but could not reproduce the error.
I removed the `proxy` parameter from the `p.chromium.launch()` statement. Maybe try that.

Comment: Yeah it appears sometimes, not always. I cannot, because the website block my server ip, thats why u need to use proxies

Comment: Maybe try a high number like `100000` instead of `0`.

Comment: The `30000ms exceeded` is the default value for the *overall* test timeout, not the navigate timeout.  I'm not sure where this is configured in [tag:python] though.

Comment: `page.goto(link, timeout = 0)` can hang forever, stifling errors. It's OK to set it to a few minutes or even an hour or so, but blocking forever is overkill and never really necessary. If there's something abnormal, I'd want a report of that situation so it can be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (for instances in which you sometimes experience timeouts) is to just keep retrying to load the page over and over by using a `while loop` that only `breaks` out of the loop if it is successful in its `try` block. The key here (and something I learned) is the fact that the `continue` statement in the `except` block doesn't return any exception, but rather retries the code within the `while loop`

```
import sleep

while True:
  try:
    page.goto(link)       
  except:
    sleep(<SLEEP FOR SOME AMOUNT OF SECONDS>)
    continue
  break
```

The sleep is optional here, but does give your network time to recover if its a networking issue. Also if you want to have max retires (instead of infinite) you can always do:

```
retries = 1
max_retries = 10
while retries <= max_retries:
  try:
    page.goto(link)       
  except:
    sleep(<SLEEP FOR SOME AMOUNT OF SECONDS>)
    retries += 1
    continue
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")` which is faster than the default `wait_until="load"` option.

MDN [explains the difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) between the two events:

> The `load` event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to `DOMContentLoaded`, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

See my [blog post](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) on these events for more detail. It's targeted to Puppeteer but applies equally to Playwright in this case.

Using `domcontentloaded` doesn't guarantee you won't see timeouts, blocks, or other weird behaviors, since every site is unique, but it should improve your results in general.

Playwright has also added a `wait_until="commit"` option which seems even faster than `domcontentloaded` and runs before the document starts loading. I recommend using this, with the caveat that I haven't used it much myself yet (but I'll try to update this post when I do).

Going a step further and blocking resources you don't need, like those stylesheets and images that MDN mentioned, is always good practice, and can help avoid loads getting stuck waiting for a slow resource and timing out. You can also disable JS, or even look into using a simple HTTP request and a static HTML parser like BeautifulSoup, if the data you want to scrape is in the static HTML.

When you do wait for `domcontentloaded`, you'll generally want to follow it with a locator to target the specific element(s) you want to manipulate once the page loads. Avoid sleeping or waiting for a network state--these are too imprecise, which leads to flakiness and slowness. Sometimes, `wait_for_function()` or `wait_for_response()` are appropriate, but the common case solution is a locator.

Regardless of what you do, never use `timeout=0` because this turns a slow load with a visible error into a silent infinite loop. Your script will eventually need to be killed by hand to avoid becoming a zombie, and you won't have the benefit of a stack trace. Even if the script is mission-critical, you should throw an error after a few minutes, catch and log it and retry the nav so you have some visibility into the problem and can take steps to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To change timeout, I suggest you should use [page.set_default_navigation_timeout](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-set-default-navigation-timeout) because `page.set_default_navigation_timeout()` **takes priority over** `page.set_default_timeout()`, `browser_context.set_default_timeout()` and `browser_context.set_default_navigation_timeout()`.

Disable timeout by setting timeout value to `0` is not recommended because it could wait forever. Instead, please use a big timeout value like `600_000` ms (10 minutes).

```py
page.set_default_navigation_timeout(600_000)
```

And as @ggorlen suggested, you should add [`wait_until`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-goto-option-wait-until) option to your `page.goto()`.
For best practice, please add wait logic to before and after doing actions.

This may not related to your case, but do the site using some form of [rate limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting)? If so, you should slowing down your scrapping.